# Using then after Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have a lot of JS experience but I am trying to call an API on a mouse over event, so that I can display some user information in a Bootstrap popover.

I am almost there, however my popover is not displaying, as the function is simply not being called after the Ajax code finishes.

```
function getUserProfile(email){

   return $.ajax({
        url: my_url + email,
        method: 'GET',
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);  // this works ok and we get data back
            return data;  // we get to here ok
        },
        async: true
    });
}
$(".my-link-popup").off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function (){
    getUserProfile(this.href).then(
        function(x){
            console.log(x) // we don't get to here at all
            $(this).popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: "<span>x.displayName</span>",
                    content: "Some nice content"
                });
            $(this).popover('show');
        }
    )
})
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's odd, it should be fine. (You might try removing the `success` handler in the `ajax` options, but I would expect the code to work as-is.) That said, here in 2021, there's really not much rason to use jQuery's `ajax` method. Just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

Comment: (Side note: You can remove `async: true`. It's the default.)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and remove those for now

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: The value returned by the `success` function isn't used, so you don't need `return data`.

Comment: Barmar - I simplified the code by removing two lines which set those.  They work and the getUserProfile method returns the correct data

Comment: data = {};  I wasn't sure what to pass here as the API doesnt need it

Comment: Then just leave out the option.

Comment: In a `GET` request, the data is added as URL query parameters.

Comment: @user3437721 try removing the success callback then check

Answer (score 0):

The function has its own `context` so `this` may be of the function so either use arrow function notation or you can use variable to reference outside context with `self`.

```js
$(".my-link-popup").off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function () {
  let self = this;
  getUserProfile(this.href).then((x) => {
    console.log(x) // we don't get to here at all
    $(self).popover({
      html: true,
      title: "<span>x.displayName</span>",
      content: "Some nice content"
    });
    $(self).popover('show');
  })
});
```

---

```js
$(".my-link-popup").off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function () {
  getUserProfile(this.href).then((x) => {
    console.log(x) // we don't get to here at all
    $(this).popover({
      html: true,
      title: "<span>x.displayName</span>",
      content: "Some nice content"
    });
    $(this).popover('show');
  })
});
```

Comment: What did you change and why?

Comment: What does changing `self` to `this` have to do with not getting to `console.log(x)`?

Comment: @Barmar added information to the answer

Comment: His use of `self` was the standard way to solve the context problem before arrow functions were created. Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: @Barmar as the question stated that popover is not showing I addressed that problem.

Comment: It also says that the `console.log(x)` is not showing. The problem is that the function isn't being called at all, not just the popover.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it looks like the function was working, but it didn't like the $(this).

This works:

```
function getUserProfile(email){

   return $.ajax({
        url: my_url + email,
        method: 'GET',
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);  // this works ok and we get data back
            return data;  // we get to here ok
        },
        async: true
    });
}
$(".my-link-popup").off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function (){
let context = this; //added this line
    getUserProfile(this.href).then(
        function(x){
            console.log(x)
            $(context).popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: "<span>x.displayName</span>",
                    content: "Some nice content"
                });
            $(context).popover('show');
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: That's just the same answer as the one that was posted previously. It also doesn't fit the question, where you clearly said *"`console.log(x) // we don't get to here at all`"* The value of `this` has no effect whatsoever on whether you get to that `console.log`, so telling us you didn't get there completely mis-stated the problem (if, again, this was the answer). (If `this` was the problem, the way to solve it in modern JavaScript is an arrow function.)